# wordpress and custom pages

Tags: php, html, wordpress, content-management-system

I'm about to choose a platform for a new website I'm building.

The website will have quit a bit of content, and nontechnical personnel updating it so I definitely need a CMS. But also I would like to have the option of manually creating pages which will then communicate with a database (like registration forms, forms etc...), or jquery function and so on.

Now I know wordpress is really good at content management, so it is my number one choice, but since I used wordpress only as an end user and never really as a programmer, I was wandering how customization it is for creating hard coded pages. I know there are a lot of plugins out there, but in case I would like to write stuff from zero, how hard it is to hard code stuff in, while still using the same design and feel of the website?

I'm guessing I'm asking if this is a good idea to use wordpress for a website which will require a lot of custom features down the line.

Comment: I'm not sure this is the right place for this question. No it's not that difficult to extend wordpress. It depends on what the end result is. If it's still primarily a CMS/blog then use it, if not then probably don't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wordpress will give you the full control on customizing any page template. It is very easy to do.

Please check this link http://www.expand2web.com/blog/custom-page-template-wordpress/

It is of course a good idea to use wordpress in your case. You can customize it as you need also a nontechnical person can update it easily.

Comment: Great, thanks, this is exactly the answer I was looking for.